# PDFs scrolling not smooth

Tags: pdf

I'm using a Macbook Pro. There's a always a response delay when I scroll fast. Is there a way to load the entire file onto Memory/ pre-render it? And would that fix the problem?

Edit- I was using Google chrome and Adobe Acrobat all this time, Preview fixes the problem.

Comment: What are you actually using to view PDFs, preview?

Comment: @kyrias Wow- I was using Chrome all this time. I just opened up my 112mb file in Preview and it's blazingly fast. Chrome and Adobe Acrobat Pro pretty much sucks for PDFs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Reading PDFs on Macs are slow on Adobe Reader and Chrome. I don't think there's a direct solution.

You can also try another PDF reader called [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net), which has more features and capabilities than Preview. 
It's as smooth as Preview too!

Comment: Skim does feel more responsive than Preview. However the text is rendered much darker.

<a href="http://imgur.com/6ywEOM4&Q6QPHIM#1" Here's a screenshot comparison on Imgur</a>